# Pycharm using Conda Package Manager cannot install new packages?

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, package, installation

I have been trying to install other packages and also upgrade the pandas package in the Pycharm IDE. I read through the official Pycharm documentation here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html, however it does not explain the case I'm seeing.

I click into the **Settings** -> **Project Interpreter** -> **+** (sign on top right) and this should open the available packages window. However, this window displays "Nothing to show". What is happening here? I tried to then click **Manage Repositories** which is constantly loading and displays "Nothing to show" again.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHG6V.png)

Comment: _+ (sign on top right)_ On the top right? Can you share some screenshots?

Comment: Drop `idea.log` from **Help | Show Log in ...** to PyCharm support at pycharm-support@jetbrains.com There're some similar issues in the IDE bug tracker (e.g. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-35791) but all of them are fixed as far as I can see so make sure you are using the latest available PyCharm version.